# Multiple inheritance frome more than one interface

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

Let me have a template class ( `class Entry<T>`), I want to make this class inherit from tow interfaces (`IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`), I've tried this:

```
class Entry<T> where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
 /* Whatever in the class */
}
```

and I've tried the next code:

```
class Entry<T> : IEquatable<T>, where T : IComparable<T>
{
 /* Whatever in the class */
}
```

but non of them worked correctly, I don't know Why, anyone Can help me to know how I can use multiple interfaces inheritance?

Comment: you should replace T in the Interfaces with the name of the class so `IComparable<Entry<T>>` unless you are trying to only compare or Equate the `T` type and not the `Entry<T>` class.

Comment: You should state what you mean when you say they don't work correctly so we know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes that's right, I tried IComparable<Entry<T>> and IEquatable<Entry<T>> but it still Error, it show me the folloing message (There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<T> ) when I define an array of Entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following signature to implement both  `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`:

```
public class Entry<T> : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    public int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        //compare logic... 
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return CompareTo(other) == 0;
    }
}
```

Your first example is using the `where` clause to form a generic type constraint that says "*only accept a type argument that implements  `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`*".

Your second example has invalid syntax. It looks like you're trying to say *"The `T`  `IEquatable<T>` takes must implement `IComparable<T>`"*. If you want to do that then you must also constrain `T` in `class Entry<T>`.

Comment: how to re-implement (IComparable<T>) methods in Entry class?

Comment: @lonelyman You need to implement the method `CompareTo` as defined by `IComparable` and define how to compare two instances of `Entry`. Do you understand?

Comment: public int CompareTo(Entry<KT> other)
        {
            return this.Key.CompareTo(other);
        } //is that true????????

Comment: I updated my post. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2